# ubuntu ssh banner

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm running Ubuntu x64 server 10.04 on a virtual slice and want to get rid of the lines in bold (and the blank line) below:

```
$ ssh user@server
Linux jm 2.6.32.12-rscloud #26 SMP Mon May 17 12:35:34 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Mon Oct 11 04:42:07 2010 from xx.xx.xx.xx
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove or comment the following line in your `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_motd.so
```